How to define in react native (at least in android) the POP ON SCREEN option for notifications (like in manifest file)?
I'm trying to make my push notification to be read or to show as a pop on screen (when device is unlocked, show notifications as a banner across the top of the screen).
I've already added android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS , android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK. The .POST_NOTIFICATION deals with asking for permission to allow the notification but I still need to manually check on the app's info under settings and select on the notification channel and toggle the POP ON SCREEN option there. I've been searching for the name, term or tag in which this feature belongs but nada.

